# Justification for Interchange of integral and sum

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. I would like to write this equality
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ixt}d\mu(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(it)^{n}}{n!}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^{n}d\mu(x).$$
This is a part of an exercise from Probability giving together the Fourier transform and moments of a measure.

I want to ask, what is the right (rigorous!) justification for the interchange of the sum and the integral in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a rather special probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, $e^{-x^2/2}dx/\sqrt{2\pi})$ in order to guarantee the convergence of the sequence of integrals on the right hand side of your equation, and even in that case you would need to examine their rate of growth in order to allow for integrating the sum term by term. In general the formula is not correct.